# Необходимо в прошивке marlin найти часть кода отвечающего за подачу питания на нагреваемый стол

Tags: arduino, перекодировка, прошивка

Вводные: Есть прошивка marlin для 3д принтера и среда разработки где можно этот код редактировать. Никак не могу найти участок кода где происходит решение греть стол или нет. Необходимо в итоге дополнить код так чтобы стол грелся периодами. То есть если целевая температура не достигнута греем 5 секунд остываем 5 секунд и так до того пока не будет достигнута нужная температура, если достигли отключаемся.

Comment: Укажите версию marlin. Ветки 1.x и 2.x очень сильно отличаются

Answer (score 0):

Всё, что относится к регулированию температуры находится в классе `Temperature`, описанном в файла temperature.h и temperature.cpp

Comment: Да, благодарю! Я это знал ещё до того как задал вопрос :) Но там так много намешано, что мне пришлось неделю разбираться в коде. В итоге нашел нужную строку. Как появлюсь дома, отвечу на сабж. :))

Answer (score 0):

> То есть если целевая температура не достигнута греем 5 секунд остываем 5 секунд и так до того пока не будет достигнута нужная температура, если достигли отключаемся.

По описанию очень похоже на bang-bang режим. Но но работает чуть иначе. Раз в `BED_CHECK_INTERVAL` (по умолчанию 5 секунд) проверяем температуру. Если ниже заданной, то включаем нагрев, если выше, то выключаем.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Может похоже, но не совсем. Мне нужно именно до того как стол достигнет нужную температуру прерывать нагрев. Это из за того что стол самодельный и прогревается очень быстро. И чтобы не спалить его, и было принято решение сделать постепенный нагрев с включением отключением. Ниже отвечу, как это сделать.

Comment: В таком случае вам нужно обычное PID-регулирование, которое в Marlin реализовано уже давно. Оно как раз и обеспечивает отключение до окончательного прогрева, с учетом скорости изменения температуры. Но если стол запитан от 220, то придется использовать твердотельное реле. Обычное не выдержит такого количества переключений.

Comment: Герман Борисов, хорошо, я впринцепе уже переписал код. Реле автомобильное поставил. У меня диодом половино отсекается и идет 110 вольт. На практике пробовал реле такое использовать с напряжением из сети. Долго работает каждый день на протяжении года гонял, работало. :)) По поводу Пид регулирования, где посмотреть настройку этого параметра не подскажите?

Comment: @MIHAnik22, Configuration.h, секция начинается с комментария `============================= PID > Bed Temperature Control ===============`